# Can validate_uniqueness_of work with custom scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, activemodel, named-scopes

I'm working on an RoR project and I'd like to have a uniqueness validation on one of my models that checks against a custom scope:

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :keyword_list

  scope :active, -> { where("expiration > ?", DateTime.now) }

  validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: [:active, :keyword_list_id] }
end
```

Only, this doesn't work. It checks the database for an active column, which doesn't exist and throws this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column keywords.active does not exist
```

So, my question is there any way to make this work, or do I have to write a custom validator? And if so, are there any tips on what it should look like to hitting the database too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you will have to write a custom validation.

Try this.

```
# In app/models/keyword.rb

validate :freshness

private

def freshness
  if Keyword.active.find_by(name: self.name, keyword_list_id: self.keyword_list_id)
    errors.add(:base, "Name is not fresh enough.") # Fails the validation with error message
  end
end
```

Here's another interesting point, you **cannot** rely on `validates_uniqueness_of`, or any other uniqueness validator in rails, because validations are not run atomically, meaning that if two identical records are inserted at the same time, and there is no **SQL constraint** validating uniqueness, the ruby validations will pass and both records will be inserted.

What I'm trying to say here is that if your validations are mission-critical, use a SQL constraint.